# Finite content which is not a pre-measure

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

I've just run into an apparent contradiction and it would be great if someone could explain where I'm going wrong:

A basic theorem in measure theory states that for a finite content $\mu$ on a ring of subsets (of some set $X$) one has

*$\mu$ is a pre-measure if and only if for every sequence $(A_n)\subset \mathfrak{P}(X)$ with $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$ one has $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ and $\mu(A_n)\downarrow 0$.*

Now consider the following example:

Take $X=\mathbb Q$ and define the half-ring $H:=\{(a,b]\cap\mathbb Q : a\leq b,\;a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ and the function 
$$\tilde\mu:H\to\mathbb R\\ \tilde\mu((a,b]\cap\mathbb Q)=b-a.$$
The function $\tilde\mu$ is a finite content and can be uniquely extended to the ring $R$ generated by $H$ which defines a finite content $\mu$ on $R$. 
It seems pretty clear to me that this $\mu$ satisfies $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ and $\mu(A_n)\downarrow 0$ for every $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$, but it isn't $\sigma$-additive as the following proof shows:

Consider the interval $(0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ and let $r_1,r_2,...$ be a counting of this set. Let $I_k$ be intervals centered at $r_k$ of length $2^{-k-1}$. Then one has
$$(0,1]\cap\mathbb Q \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k,\\
\mu((0,1]\cap\mathbb Q)=1\\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(I_k) = \frac 1 2
$$
So $\mu$ isn't a pre-measure which contradicts the above theorem.

(A *content* is a map $\tilde\mu:\mathfrak{P}(X)\to\mathbb R_+$ such that $\tilde\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\tilde\mu(A\cup B)=\tilde\mu(A)+\tilde\mu(B)$ for $A\cap B=0$)

Comment: @ Frank  Is the  sentence -''It seems pretty clear to me that this $\mu$ satisfies $\mu(A_1)<\infty$ and $\mu(A_n)\downarrow 0$ for every $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$''  true?

Let $A_n=(0,1]\cap\mathbb Q \setminus  \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k$.

 Then  $A_n\downarrow \emptyset$ but the condition $\mu(A_n) \downarrow 0$  fails because $\mu(((0,1]\cap\mathbb Q) \setminus  \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k)=\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^n((0,1]\cap\mathbb Q) \setminus I_k)\ge 1/2$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you! I had been confused by an exercise from a book which seemed to claim that $\mu(A_n)\downarrow 0$ was true.