# A content which is lower and upper continuous, but not sigma additive

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to do this exercise:
[image]

I'm having trouble proving that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-additive, since $\cup^{\infty}_{i=1}A_i=A\in \mathcal{A}$ I've been looking at sets $I_k$ with $\mu(I_k)=1/2^k$ or sets that give divergent series, but to no avail.

Any hint?

Edit: I thought I had found an answer in this [page of Math.Stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911086/finite-content-which-is-not-a-pre-measure), but the example there doesn't seem to work, since $\cup^{\infty}_{i=1}I_i\cap \mathbb{Q} \notin \mathcal{A}$ nor do they seem to be mutually disjoint...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$. Define iteratively a sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ as follows:

- $n=1$: $$A_1 := \mathbb{Q} \cap \bigg( \max\left\{0,x_1- \frac{1}{2^3}\right\}, x_1 \bigg].$$
- $n \to n+1$: Suppose that we have already defined $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. Set$$k_{n+1} := \inf\{j \geq 1; x_j \notin A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n\}$$ and define $$A_{n+1} := \mathbb{Q} \cap (x_{k_{n+1}}-r_{n+1},x_{k_{n+1}}]$$ where $r_{n+1} \in (0,2^{-n-3}]$ is chosen such that $A_{n+1} \subseteq (0,1)$ and $$A_{n+1} \cap (A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n) = \emptyset.$$

The so-defined sets are mutually disjoint and $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1) = \bigcup_{k \geq 1} A_k$. Since

$$\mu(\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)) = 1$$

but

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(A_n) \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{-n-2} = \frac{1}{4} < 1$$

we conclude that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: Saz, thanks for the answer. One doubt: how do you know that  the union of the $A_k$s equals the desired set?

Comment: @Klenke2ed Note that $x_1,\ldots,x_{k_n-1} \in A_n$ and $k_n \geq n$. Hence, $\{x_j\}_{j\geq 1} \subseteq \bigcup_j A_j$.

Comment: Saz, thanks for the help. I must say that somehow this seems highly unintuitive to me. =D  For example, let's just order the enumeration so that $x_1=1$. then $x_{k_2}=1-2^3$. Next, we have $x_{k_3}=1-2^{-3}-2^{-3-1}$, with $r_k=2^{-3-k}$, but then I would not be able to cover the whole (0,1]... I think I'm doing a mistake in assuming that we can order the enumeration...

Comment: @Klenke2ed The sets do **not** cover $(0,1)$, but $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Note that $\bigcup_k (x_k-r_k,x_k]$ covers $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ for **any** $r_k>0$; all the fuss is just to make the intervals disjoint.

Comment: Also, why would the infimum be well defined in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "well-defined"? The infimum does always exist.

Comment: Inf [-infty, 0] exists? I thought it didn't exist in this case.  I'm sorry if this will sound stupid, but I was also wondering if we could have the case that $x_{k_{n+1}}\in \cup^n A_i$? Thanks

Comment: @Klenke2ed Well, but no such thing happens in our framework. If you prefer, you can define $k_{n+1}$ as follows: Choose the smallest $j \geq 1$ such that $x_j \notin A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$. (The only "bad" thing which could happen is that no such $j$ exists, but in this case we can simply define $A_{n+1} = A_{n+2} = \ldots = \emptyset$ as $\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j$ covers $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.) This also shows that $x_{k_{n+1}} \notin \bigcup^n A_j$.

Comment: I think I got it. =)

Comment: @saz this is a beautiful solution, but what perplexes me is why this goes wrong if we include all reals in $(0,1]$, not just $(0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$. Clearly the content $\mu$ is just Lebesgue measure in this case, which is certainly $\sigma$-additive. But if we take the enumeration $\{x_j\}_{j \geq 1}$ of $(0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ and define $A_i$ as you did, but without $\cap \mathbb Q$, can we find explicit $y \in (0,1] \setminus \bigcup_i A_i$?

Comment: @Klenke2ed I think (possibly to answer my own question?) the problem with your enumeration $x_1 = 1$, $x_{k_2} = 1-2^{-3}$, $x_{k_3} = 1-2^{-3}-2^{-4}$, etc., is that this "enumeration" would not actually enumerate all $(0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$. It would be like trying to enumerate $(0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ by saying $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 1/2$, ..., $x_n = 1/n$, ... It's a countable collection of rationals, but it misses a fair number of them.

Comment: @DFord Well, since the sequence $(A_n)_n$ satisfies $$\mu \left( \bigcup_n A_n \right) \leq \sum_n \mu(A_n) \leq \frac{1}{4}$$ there have to be plenty of such $y$. Not sure about an explicit construction...

Comment: Of course; the logic is irrefutable. Perhaps this is one of those situations where real analysis gets just impossible to visualize... a real mind-bender

Answer (score 5):

Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a semiring and $\mu$ is a content on $\mathcal{A}$, it follows that $\mu$ is a premeasure if and only if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive. Thus to find a counter-example for defying that $\mu$ is a premeasure, we only need to find a counter-example to show that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-subadditive. To do this, as you mentioned, let $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of $(0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and let $B_k = (x_k-2^{-k-2},x_k+2^{-k-2}]\cap\mathbb{Q}\in\mathcal{A}$ for $k=1,2,\dots$.

Thus, $(0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_k$, but $$\mu((0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}) = 1 > \frac{1}{2}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(B_k)$$
This shows that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-subadditive.

This exercise is very interesting..

Comment: In this way, you don't bother to ensure B_k to be disjoint, you only care about subadditivity, and it does not require B_k to be disjoint.

Comment: The sets $B_k = (x_k-2^{-k-2},x_k-2^{-k-2}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ should be $B_k = (x_k-2^{-k-2},x_k+2^{-k-2}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the mistake.